# Bootstrap 3 Navbar with permanent search box

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've found an example very close of what I'm trying to get, from [this website](http://www.mentful.com/2014/06/22/fixed-search-navbar-with-bootstrap-3-0/).

The source code (as required by SO):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="#">CompAny</a>
         <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">C</a>
         <form class="navbar-form pull-left" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
               <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Browse Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Active Courses</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Relevant fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KSCvB/10/light/).

But in my case I'd prefer that the search bar is aligned to the right, as in this mockup I made with an image editor:

For a small screen:

[image: small screen]

For a larger screen:

[image: large sceen]

Comment: you should be able to use bootstraps 'pull-right' class, but I tried on your fiddle and it doesn't look like bootstrap is loaded there...

Comment: looks like you navbar-collapse collapse div is throwing it off. When I remove that out of there, it pulls right like you want. I'll try to play around more if I have time...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I "kind of" figured it out. Your navbar-header class was using a pull-left. And it was only using the space that it needed. So if all your content was the size of the whole row, then you wouldn't have noticed, but if your content only took up half the size, then you see the issue that you have.

So, I just "closed" the navbar-header div, and started a new div and now your search bar goes to the right. You can play with this bootply to get the rest of your stuff back in there...

http://www.bootply.com/WIjcWyD0Gt

Here's updated version with your regular menu items back in. If you want these on the right side of your menu, then throw them to the new div that I created for the search form.

http://www.bootply.com/P7njftNANB

Here's the code in case bootply is not available:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="pull-right">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left">
         <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="#">CompAny</a>
         <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">C</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Browse Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Active Courses</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
       </div>
       <div>
        <div class="pull-right">
         <form class="navbar-form pull-right" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
               <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
      <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you hit the same bump as me: http://i.imgur.com/zX1MSqd.png when "collapsed", the search bar jumps to another line. On Firefox it aligns to the right, and on Chrome (device emulation) it takes all available width. I'd rather have the search bar in the nav bar as a single line.

Comment: After 1 hour of fiddling i've found a solution i like. Thanks for your very valuable help! http://www.bootply.com/ZzvAxkJEbd

Comment: Please include the relevant code from your Bootply link(s) in your answer. Should Bootply change, go/be down, or remove your example completely, your answer will become useless to users in the future.